# Excel results of Index-Match and Exact do not work even though Exact works with specific references

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm building a spreadsheet to verify training attendance.

Here's an image of the two tables (trimmed from original)
[image]

Here's what I'm trying to do:

- Right 4 characters of Table 1!A3 (Contains store name and number; last 4 are store number)
- Index-Match on those same 4 characters of Table 1!A3 to find the reference in Table 2 (Attendance Record):Column 8 (StoreNumber)

Formula attempted all return #N/A:
First - what I'd like to do is use EXACT so that I return "TRUE" or "FALSE": `=EXACT(RIGHT([@[Name]],4),INDEX(tblFlowMart,MATCH(RIGHT([@[Name]],4),tblFlowMart[StoreNumber],0),8))`

Second - just the INDEX-MATCH: `=INDEX(tblFlowMart,MATCH(RIGHT([@[Name]],4),tblFlowMart[StoreNumber],0),8)` which also returns #N/A.

BUT...when I use `=EXACT(RIGHT([@[Name]],4),'Table2'!H11)` (H is the 8th column) I get "TRUE"

It seems like the table references are not working whereas if I do an exact reference R1C1 then it works.

Am I doing something wrong with the Index-Match?

Comment: What is `tblFlowMart` is it a single column or a 2d table?

Comment: `tblFlowMart` is a 2d table; column 8 (`tblFlowMart[StoreNumber]`] stores the value that I want to return and compare in the `Exact` function.

Comment: then that should be what the INDEX references: `INDEX(tblFlowMart[StoreNumber]`

Comment: If you remove the exact function and start from index it looks alright. What add the EXACT before it all?

Comment: @scott - not sure I follow; INDEX references the array `tblFlowMart` then the MATCH looks in the specified column.  When I use Evaluate to review the formula I just get an #N/A for the whole INDEX portion

Comment: You need to specify the output column one of two ways, either by only including the column in the first criterion of INDEX or by using the third criterion and specify the column number: `INDEX(tblFlowMart[Store Number],MATCH(RIGHT([@[Name]],4),tblFlowMart[Store Number],0))` or `INDEX(tblFlowMart,MATCH(RIGHT([@[Name]],4),tblFlowMart[Store Number],0),8)`

Comment: @scott I fixed my formula(s) and still get #N/A.  PB - the Exact is to give me a TRUE/FALSE which is what I want to display rather than just the Store Number

Comment: Then it is not finding a MATCH.  Try just the MATCH part of the formula.  Also note that `RIGHT()` returns a string and if you are trying to compare a string to a number it will not find the match.  It sure would be helpful if you would include a [mcve] with test data, so we are not guessing.

Comment: Based on your data your match should be: `MATCH(--RIGHT([@[Name]],4),tblFlowMart[Store Number],0)`

Comment: Scott - that worked!  So, why the hyphens?  What does that do?

Comment: As stated earlier RIGHT returns a string and a string does not match a number.  the double unary (--) basically does `-1*-1*RIGHT()` to turn the result into a number.

Comment: If you add `+0` to your `RIGHT` part of the function: `RIGHT([@[Name]],4)+0` it will not be seen as text anymore, but as a number. `=INDEX(tblFlowMart,MATCH(RIGHT([@[Name]],4)+0,tblFlowMart[StoreNumber],0),8)`

Comment: Thanks for the help guys.  I'll accept the solution if you guys want to post one of the ideas above.